# Two Codes Diverged - Left and Right Side Panels - How to get the code from one to work on the other?

Tags: html, css

My portfolio website has sidebars that open on the top, bottom, left, right side, depending which one I choose. I am just using the left and right. When I decrease the screen size, the code written for the left side works as it should; the small image, table and button stay aligned.

The problem is the right side. When the screen size is reduced, the button centers itself on the page instead of staying aligned with the image and table. I realize that the code for the right and left panels is different (aside from being left, or right) and was Not intentional.

For whatever reason, I cannot get the code from the left side to work on the right side. It seems something in this snippet of code is causing the issues:

```html
<div style="text-align: left; margin-bottom: 36px; margin-top: 47px;">
```

vs

```html
<div class="content" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-end;">
```

Again, my intentions were never to diverge the left and right code. It was an accident when I was designing the website to have left panels only. When I created the right side panel, I could not get that same code to work. So, just to get it working for the full size screen, I did what I had to do to get it to work; it works excellent on normal, average computer screens and large tablets. The code for the phone sized screens is broken and I really need it to work.

I appreciate any help with this. Here is the code for the right and left panels:

```html
<!---------------------------------------------------- ocean --------------------------------------------------------->
<section id="ocean" class="spotlight style2 right">
  <span class="image fit main"><img src="images/deck.jpg" alt="" /></span>

  <div class="content">

    <div style="text-align: left; margin-bottom: 36px; margin-top: 47px;">
      <img src="images/sailing-again.avif" alt="" style="max-width: 15em; height: auto; margin-bottom: 12px;" class="bordered-image" />
    </div>

    <!-- Table -->
    <section>
      <div class="table-wrapper" style="margin-top: 47px; margin-bottom: 47px;">
        <div style="max-width: 15em; height: auto;">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td align="left">project <br>manager</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right">oceania cruises</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; margin-top: 47px; margin-bottom: 22px;">
      <ul class="actions" style="list-style: none; margin-bottom: 0;">
        <li><a href="../ocean.html" class="button small">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;oceania cruises&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#188" class="goto-next scrolly">Next</a>
</section>
<!---------------------------------------------------- ocean --------------------------------------------------------->

<!--------------------------------------------- 188 --------------------------------------------------------------->
<section id="188" class="spotlight style2 left">
  <span class="image fit main"><img src="images/188fs07.jpg" alt="" /></span>

  <div class="content" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-end;">

    <div style="margin-bottom: .5em; margin-top: .5em;">
      <img src="images/188fs-crop.jpg" alt="" style="max-width: 15em; height: auto; margin-bottom: 12px;" class="bordered-image" />
    </div>

    <!-- Table -->
    <section>
      <div class="table-wrapper" style="margin-top: 2em; margin-bottom: 3em;">
        <div style="max-width: 15em; height: auto;">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td align="left">architect</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right">188 front street | private residence</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <div style="text-align: right; margin-top: .5em; margin-bottom: 0em;">
      <ul class="actions" style="list-style: none; margin-bottom: 0;">
        <li><a href="../188.html" class="button small">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;188 front street&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
  <a href="#ocean" class="goto-next scrolly">Next</a>
</section>
<!--------------------------------------------------- 188 -------------------------------------------------------->
```